# Difference between two dates and times from a SharePoint List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, custom-formatting

I am working with data from a SharePoint list in the format

> "hh:mm dd/mm/yy"

in Excel. I would like to find the difference in nearest hours from a start and end time to make a box and whisker plot of total time expended for a given manufacturing process.

I tried the TimeValue function, which worked in another sheet where the start and end times for time periods that were over the same day. I have also had trouble with the hours and minutes since they are retuned in one or two digit values.

`=INT(M2-L2)&"days"&TEXT(M2-L2,"h""hrs""m""mins""")`,

and have used the left function to capture the days and multiply it by 24 to get the number of days. I am not very experienced with excel.

Comment: Why have you included VBA as a tag? Are you working through VBA or just on the worksheet with worksheet functions? Also, can you include sample data with expected output. You can just use some mock-up markdown sample data. That will help answering this question.

Comment: As JvdV said we could use some sample data and examples of current and expected output. I've tried the formulas you're working with now and they seem to work as expected, which makes me unsure of what the problem is. Also if you want to round this to the nearest hour you can add a MRound function in your formula.

Comment: Start15:07 04/27/17 End 13:00 04/29/17 Time 1days21hrs53mins Expected Output: 46 hrs

Comment: I wasn't sure if a macro might be useful here, or if it could be accomplished through a formula

Comment: Are these values text values that look like a date/time value or are they actual date/time values?

Comment: They are actual time and date values, I think my issue is trying to find something that would output the amount of hours between the 2 columns as a number value.

Comment: @CrisWarren, I have posted an answer based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are truely date/time values as you said you could simply substract the older one from the newer one and format the outcome in two different ways to return the amount of hours as an integer:

Your sample data:

[image]

1) You could use the `TEXT` function to format an outcome like so:

```
=TEXT(A2-A1,"[H]")
```

2) You could subtract the two values (`=A2-A1`) and format the cell with a custom format:

```
Right click > Cell Properties > Number tab > Custom format > [H]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!